# Create a view by Filter custom column has no data

Tags: 2010, document-library, view

I have document library and it has 3 columns ( column1,columm2,column3) they are belonging to a content type.

Here How I create a view and it will show only those documents that column3 has no value.

Comment: Which datatype you have used for that custom column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Filter like below.

Select Column3 Is Equal To "" (do not enter anything in textbox)

Answer (score 3):

In your view, filter content on column3 as **is equal to** and leave the value field empty. In the example below, my column name is "Sometimes empty".

[image]

This will filter out items that doesn't have a value in column3.